# Retrieve and generate WCF Reference.svcmap by command line or programmatically?

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2012

Usually when I update/add new service reference I would just do it in Solution Explorer in Visual Studio (Update Service Reference / Add Services Reference), but for a requirement, I have to do it with command line or programmatically right now.

I read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms729834.aspx

It allows me to retrieve the metadata, but it doesn't generate the `Reference.svcmap` like we did in Visual Studio.

Is there any tool or library can do that?

Comment: Yes!! It's called [`svcutil.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx) and should be installed on any system that has WCF on it

Answer (score 0):

Use Developer Command Prompt:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat"

```
svcutil http://www.webservicex.net/sendsmsworld.asmx

svcutil /t:metadata http://www.webservicex.net/sendsmsworld.asmx
```

This will generate:

```
output.config  
SendSMSWorld.cs  
www.webservicex.net.wsdl
```

I'm not sure about svcmap, thsi seems to be something from Visual Studio

```
                   -= EXAMPLES =-

 svcutil http://service/metadataEndpoint
    - Generate client code from a running service or online metadata documents.

 svcutil *.wsdl *.xsd /language:C#
    - Generate client code from local metadata documents.

 svcutil /dconly *.xsd /language:VB
    - Generate Data Contract types in VisualBasic from local schema documents.

 svcutil /t:metadata http://service/metadataEndpoint
    - Download metadata documents from running services

 svcutil myAssembly.dll
    - Generate metadata documents for Service Contracts and associated types in
    an assembly

 svcutil myServiceHost.exe /serviceName:myServiceName
    - Generate metadata documents for a service, and all associated Service
    Contracts and data types in an assembly

 svcutil myServiceHost.exe /dconly
    - Generate metadata documents for data types in an assembly

 svcutil /validate /serviceName:myServiceName myServiceHost.exe
    - Verify service hosting

 svcutil /t:xmlserializer myContractLibrary.exe
    - Generate serialization types for XmlSerializer types used by any Service
    Contracts in the assembly
```